# Response.ContentType = "text/csv" causes XML error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, content-type

I've got an odd issue.

I'm creating a DataTable type my application then converting it to a CSV so the user can download the data.

I set the content type like this:

```
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".csv");
    var responseBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.Rows.Count * data.Columns.Count * 30);
```

Now, this works well for all data sizes in my development environment, and for small amounts of data on my production environment, but when it gets to a larger size (say, more than about 4000 rows) on production Firefox gives me the error:

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
```

Any ideas? There are no errors in Elmah, which I'm using to log.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible the request is timing out and firefox interprets this as a blank document?

Comment: Good call, it would be worth using Firebug or some such to verify that what is arriving at the browser is indeed what you expected to be sending.

Comment: Thanks @jwsample and @Carson63000.

I think I've found the issue, and there's no way you could have picked it from the info I gave! But it looks like you are on the right track. I think it's a time out and the most likely place for the time out to be occurring is on the load balancer, explaining why it only happens on production.

Comment: I'll update this post when I know if this has solved the issue, but I think what I/we can take from the issue is that this particular error "XML Parsing Error: no element found" simply means that nothing has been returned by the server (in this case). Also, we know that the conversion to CSV was taking a long time. Together this definitely points to a time out. Determining where the time out seems to be the toughest part! I narrowed down to the load balancer after experimenting with timeout settings in IIS to no avail.

Comment: I then ran the app from the production server (by passing the load balancer) and found the error didn't happen.

Another point is that in Charles I noticed the request always ended at about the 30 second mark - more evidence to a time out.

Thank you both again for your input.

Comment: @Ev Use a HTTP sniffer like Fiddler to see what exactly the server is or isn't sending to the browser. Then you won't have to make any guesses. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I found out the timeout was occuring on the Load Balancer, so I had to up it there.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a timeout issue on the Load balancer.